# free webex platform

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access, webex

there is any solution like webex but free of charge?

The most interesting thing about webex for me is the chance of sending a link and get the costumer linked to me with just a ckick from him.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used [WebHuddle](https://www.webhuddle.com/) with good results in the past, also [Microsoft SharedView](http://connect.microsoft.com/site/sitehome.aspx?SiteID=94)

Answer (score 1):

I've found plain old VNC in view-only mode to do the job pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

Skype does screen sharing now so is a free solution...

Answer (score 0):

You could try CoPilot.com I've used that in the past. VNC with a server can be good. There is a way to setup a client so that it auto connects to the server and tunnels out nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Adobe's www.acrobat.com for this feature. 
No software needs to be installed. All you need is a browser with the Flash plugin.
They even offer a free dial-in conference number for every registered user.

However, the free package allows only upto 3 users to participate in meetings.